Brake pads replaced thrice and car is under 6k miles
looking for some advice on a car purchase that I'm about to do. I'm planning to get a used 2023 gla 45 and I like the car and all. But as I was going thru the carfax report, I see that the brake pads were replaced thrice over a year's time and the car currently has a mileage of 6200 miles
The front brake pads were replaced at 4100 miles and at 4600 miles, the carfax report says 3 things

Front brake pads replaced
Brake pads replaced
Wheel(s) replaced

Again, at 6200miles, the carfax report has the following line items

Front brake pads replaced
Brake pads replaced
Rear brake pads replaced
Wheel(s) replaced

I asked the dealer about it and he gave me a vague answer...Something along the line of, sometimes brake checks accidentally get registered as brake replaced. I feel like the dealer isn't telling me something. The title still says clean and all, but is this normal and does the carfax report get miss noted like this anytime?
Also, the car is in a different state and it's kind of hard for me to go and physically check the vehicle.
Any advices on how to go about this?

A sight-unseen purchase of this nature is risky in itself. The 6200 mile failures should be considered a red flag. Replaced wheels? Why?

It's possible someone's been driving it like a lunatic and worn down the pads multiple times, in which case you don't want that car.

My Daughter recently bought a Buick with a 3.8 liter engine -- many editions after the first block. The DEALER said one owner, ignoring the part that they were the second owner and likely bought the car at an auction.  Spoke Russian very well as well to the other staff.
In short - its a DEALER.  Only politicians are trusted less.
But, we did actually get hard receipts with the old lady's home phone and primary service provider.  It is 17 years old with less than 84K miles, yet multiple service tickets on an intake manifold gasket.
I would contemplate a crooked mechanic based on my watching these records, and you should maybe the same.
OR there is an idiot that does not consider a failed rubber brake line where the cylinder locks due to debris.  And besides, they get to book more shop time and pad markup.....

100% agreement here.  Walk, better yet, run away from this "deal".  There is a problem with the vehicle.

Aye Aye Captain!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If the pads are replaced in pairs -- as they should be -- check to see if only one of the two brakes is causing the issue.  If it's a caliper, it could be the slide pins are not sliding, and dragging on one pad.  Otherwise, for drum or caliper, you can have a rubber line corroded internally and it can turn into an unseen check valve, where the hydraulic pressure pushes the pads, but cannot relieve the pressure from the master cylinder because of the snot in the rubber supply line.

Even if you suspect that this car has been thrashed – or anything that seems unusual – walk away.
Some wheels have been replaced already, which could also indicate a driver who has treated the car badly, and didn't care what they did to it.
So what else did they do to it, that you can't see from another state? And if the price is suspiciously attractive, that too is another sign.

While I agree I'd walk away from this, I"m pretty sure the "wheel replaced" statement in there is meaning the wheels were taken off for inspection or what have you and then put back (replaced) onto the vehicle. It's an odd way to annotate it for sure, but it makes a ton more sense than having the wheels replaced literally.
